# JavaScript functions are not working in ajax tabs

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

In my page I have ajax tabs and every tab consists of some javascript functions. I want to load each javascript function only when the tabs are clicked. But the functions are not working in tabs. How can I solve this?

My codes are as follows:

**PHP:**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "function check(){";
echo "alert('hello');";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";

echo "<div><a href='javascript:check();'>Check</a></div>";
```

**Ajax:**

```
new Ajax.Request(
       test.php,
    {
       method:'post',               
       onSuccess: function(data){
       var tmp=data.responseText;
       $$('.tolga').invoke('insert',tmp);
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="tolga">
    </div>
```

Comment: Is the div with the `a` and `Check` showing up, and then when you click it nothing happens? Or is `tolga` staying empty?

Comment: div with a and check is shown abut the script doesn't

Comment: I love when people say "my codes". Makes me giggle.